# Codeigniter user profile URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, profile

I have a controller called user which just loads the user profile page for now

```
class user extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($username = null){
        //load index page
        $this->load->view('profile/index');
    }

}
```

i have also routed it so i can load it from user/$username in routes

```
//user profiles pretty url
$route['user/(:any)'] = "user/index/$1";
```

the thing is i would like to change it and allow directly the users to go to their profiles without typing user/$username and instead $usernamd like mysite.com/$username...

I tried it but it messes up everything.how can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only way to achieve something like this is to add all other controllers to your routes file.

You could try something like this

```
$route['controller'] = "controller";
$route['controller/(:any)'] = "controller/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "user/$1";
```

Combined with the _remap function as stated [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping). In your users controller.

Comment: Easiest way I could think of. Maybe another approach would be creating a custom router (MY_Router) that checks if the name filled in is a controller or a username and then makes a decision.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of the [_remap function](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping)?
If you replace the index() function with this:

```
public function _remap($username = null) {
    $this->load->view('profile/index');
}
```

It will probably work. You don't have to use the routes.php.

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this for my users ; this "p" function in my users controller, mysite.com/users/p/$user_id , routes are good but I solved it like this, you could also do it do index function if you don't want something like "p"

```
function p() 
{
$total_slashes = count ( $this->uri->segment_array () );
$last = end ( $this->uri->segments );
if ($total_slashes == 3) {
$data ['userdetails'] = $this->users_model->userDetails ( $last );
// $last is our user_id
$this->load->view('profile/index');
}
}
```